# curl post request failing

Tags: linux, post, curl

I am sending a post request to my site as so :

```
curl --data "param1=value1&param2=value2" http://mysite.com/
```

But the result is the entire html page (independently of the username and the password, whether they are right or wrong)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
`curl -u username:password http://example.com`
```

to get logged on, or try this

```
curl http://username:password@example.com/?param1=xx&param2=xx
```